# mongosh toArray() is not a function

Tags: mongo-shell

We are starting to work with mongo, and want to save the results of our queries to a file for reporting needs.

I downloaded `mongosh-1.10.1-win32-x64` and `mongodb-windows-x86_64-6.0.8-signed` set up a local mongosh to test it out

I ran

```
use users
db.users.findOne()
db.users.findOne().toArray()
```

and received the following error `db.users.findOne().toArray is not a function`

How can I solve this so that I can save my results to file?